# Thymeleaf/SB How do I pass in a variable from an object to a link element's href attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, templates, thymeleaf

I want to pass in the project.url variable into the th:href attribute of the  element, but currently the URL that is navigated to is - /project/project.url/contribute        which is obviously not what  I wanted to happen.
The list above the button displays the project object's information and the URL is shown correctly.

```
    <ul>

    <span>Title: </span>
    <li th:text="${project.url}">Title</li>

    <span>Started: </span>
    <li th:text="${project.publishedOn}">Started</li>

    <span>Target: </span>
    <li th:text="${project.targets}">Target</li>

    <span>Description: </span>
    <li th:text="${project.description}">Description</li>

    <span>Amount Contributed: </span>
    <li th:text="${project.amountContributed}">Amount Contributed</li>

</ul>

<div class="contributeButton">
    <button>
 <!-- <a href="../project/' + ${project.url} + '/contribute">Contribute</a> -->
 <a th:href="@{/project/${project.url}/contribute(action='show_all')}">Contribute</a>
    </button>
</div>
```

What href do I need to put inside the link for this to work correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use concatenation to do this. I haven't tested this but give it a try:

```
<a th:href="@{'/project/' + ${project.url} + '/contribute(action=\'show_all\')'}">view</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to remove the (action) part of the string but I don't need that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should be taking advantage of Thymeleaf's [standard URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) for this:

```
<a th:href="@{/project/{url}/contribute(url=${project.url})}">view</a>
```